# How to change from email address in azure devops?

Tags: azure, email, azure-devops, devops

Is there any way to **configure** or **change** `from email address` in Azure DevOps?

Right now mail is coming with anonymous `Microsoft ID`. which is blocking in our organization.

So instead of this, we need to configure in such way that from address should be one of mail ID from our organization.
Thank you.

Comment: Not get your latest information, is the answer below helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here

Answer (score 0):

In short: no, you can not. You *do* have a couple of options though.

One would be that you could add the `azuredevops@microsoft.com` e-mail address to your company's e-mail whitelist.

Another option would be to create a [Webhook in Azure DevOps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/service-hooks/services/webhooks) and call a [Power Automate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/getting-started) flow, Azure [Logic App](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/logic-apps/) or Azure Function to send an e-mail through an allowed or company address, for instance by using M365.